# Why does my shopping cart item not have a label?

Tags: 8, commerce

I'm working on D8 site with Drupal Commerce.
I have to create a dynamic product variation and add it to cart for the user checkout.

The problem I have, is when you land on the cart page, the line item doesn't have a label (title) it replaced with the price of the item. Please refer to the attached image.

Here's my code:

```
   //create variation
            $variation = ProductVariation::create([
                'type' => 'fk_payment',
                'sku' => 'FK'.$faid,
                'status' => TRUE,
                'price' => new Price($trans->getTotal(), $trans->getCurrency()),
                'title' => "Example item label title",
              ]);

            $variation->save();

            //Load the product
            $product_id = 4;
            $product = Product::load($product_id);
            $product->addVariation($variation);
            $product->save();

            //load store
            $storeId = $product->get('stores')->getValue()[0]['target_id'];
            $store = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getStorage('commerce_store')
            ->load($storeId);
            
            //prepare cart
            $cart = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
            $cart = $cart->getCart('default', $store);
            
            if (!$cart) {
                $cart = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_provider');
                $cart = $cart->createCart('default', $store);
            }

            // Process to place order programatically.
            $cart_manager = \Drupal::service('commerce_cart.cart_manager');

            //empty the cart
            if (!empty($cart)) {
                $cart_manager->emptyCart($cart);
            }

            $cart_manager->addEntity($cart, $variation);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer.  I have to edit the cart "Views" and change the field "item" to display label.  That's it.